# spring boot cloud Zuul Proxy - hardcoded proxy route references in code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have the basics of Spring Cloud working with the gateway (with Zuul Proxy) proxying rest end points (/ui, /admin as separate microservices). I am following [spring boot blog by Dave Syer](http://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application)

```
zuul:
  routes:
    ui:
      url: http://localhost:8081
    admin:
      url: http://localhost:8082
    resource:
      url: http://localhost:9000
```

The idea is that the `gateway`(Zuul) will be running on 8080 and the front end apps (`UI` and `Admin`) would be aware of only the `gateway` and have no knowledge of `ui` and `admin` backend end URLs. The admin app would simply contact `http://localhost:8080/admin'

The setup works fine except that the front end apps (for ex: `admin`) would have to hardcode the `/admin` route as a prefix in all the JS & HTML code.  2 examples below:

Following doesn't work (in admin.js).

```
angular.module('admin', []).controller('home',
function($scope, $http) {

    var computeDefaultTemplate = function(user) {
        $scope.template = user && user.roles &&
        user.roles.indexOf("ROLE_WRITER")>0 ? "write.html" : "read.html";       
    }
```

However, following does work:

```
angular.module('admin', []).controller('home',

function($scope, $http) {

    var computeDefaultTemplate = function(user) {
        $scope.template = user && user.roles && 
        user.roles.indexOf("ROLE_WRITER")>0 ? "admin/write.html" : "admin/read.html";       
    // ..... !! NOTE the hardcoding of 'admin/' prefix route !!!

    }
```

Similar issues exist in admin app: index.html

Works (but not desired):

```
<body ng-app="admin" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" ng-controller="home">
    ...
    ..... !! NOTE the hardcoding of 'admin/' prefix route !!!
    <script src="admin/js/admin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<body ng-app="admin" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" ng-controller="home">
    ...
    <script src="js/admin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

Evidently this hardcoding of "/admin" route into all href links in all HTML and JS code in the admin is not desirable. How can I overcome this (how can I keep relative references in my admin code)?

Comment: so is this angular code on http://localhost:8082 in 'admin' service?

Comment: yes. I will edit the question with that note

Comment: If you are going through the zuul router, you have to know the context.  I don't see any way around having "/admin" in your js.  Why is that "not desirable"?

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable solution to this? I have a similar issue, where I'd like zuul to strip the prefix (e.g. /myapp/api/v1/**) so I don't have to hard code this path in my ui service (i.e. not prefix all css/js  and submit/actions)

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I still dont follow this flow. It looks like this angular code is a client and "admin/write.html" should go through zuul to http://localhost:8082/write.html? I dont know internals, but maybe when you are using 'admin' service id without 'path' then zuul is not striping prefix?

Try with it:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    admin:
      path: /admin/**
      stripPrefix: true
      url: http://localhost:8082
```